# wget command not working in cronjob

Tags: shell, cron

wget command wont work in cron?
I am using wget command in a script to hit a URL and fetch its content. I run the script manually in command prompt, it works fine. But setting same script in cron is not working.

```
wget -o wgetlog2 --output-document=wgettesting2.html "URL"
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: try with the absolute path of wget. It should be `/usr/bin/wget` for most systems

Comment: You need to indicate full paths. Take a look at the "Debugging crontab" section in http://stackoverflow.com/tags/crontab/info

Comment: [define "not working"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Where are you expecting the downloaded file to be? Check your home directory.